# ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration disappeared in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application using OAuth2 and working successfully in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 I switched Spring Boot version to 2.0.0.M7 and the application stop working.

After some debugging, I found that the class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration' is removed from the artifact 'spring-boot-autoconfigure' in 2.0.0.M7 which was doing the following initialisation...

```
@Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ResourceServerTokenServices.class)
        public UserInfoTokenServices userInfoTokenServices() {
            UserInfoTokenServices services = new UserInfoTokenServices(
                    this.sso.getUserInfoUri(), this.sso.getClientId());
            services.setRestTemplate(this.restTemplate);
            services.setTokenType(this.sso.getTokenType());
            if (this.authoritiesExtractor != null) {
                services.setAuthoritiesExtractor(this.authoritiesExtractor);
            }
            if (this.principalExtractor != null) {
                services.setPrincipalExtractor(this.principalExtractor);
            }
            return services;
        }
```

Now that this class removed, no initialization occurs and 'DefaultTokenServices' initialized in the class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer' and my application fails.

```
private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices(HttpSecurity http) {
    if (resourceTokenServices != null) {
        return resourceTokenServices;
    }
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetails());
    this.resourceTokenServices = tokenServices;
    return tokenServices;
}
```

Does anybody knows why this class is removed or is there any replacement for it?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems auto-configure delegate these configuration to Spring Security 5 until that is ready they provide a temporary jar file fulfilling the old functionality which can be reach with the following issue...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1240